# Google Drive API / Realtime API on Chrome OS - offline?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Chromebooks etc have offline versions of users' Drive files, so is there a way to use the Realtime API, which though apparently inaccessible offline, does *work* just fine offline? (my app starts in an 'inMemoryModel' mode).

Problems include that Google disallows cacheing of their API's, and that when a manifest-enhanced single-page web-app is run on a disconnected Chromebook, the user is shown a "This application cannot run offline" screen, or similar.

What if anything, is Google's plan for this, and other similar Drive API situations?

Comment: Are you asking if Realtime API can be used offline? An [SO issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259074/google-drive-realtime-api-offline-and-sync-support) was raised and suggests that it doesn't have offline support (though it can handle flaky connection)

Comment: Well, partly. The Realtime API appears perfectly happy offline, especially if using an in-memory model. But the API itself cannot be cached, and on a Chromebook, drive documents are available, but not any Drive API's, as far as I know..?